# How did the radiative flux of each gas giant planet change with respect to time (since their formation)?

Tags: temperature, planets, moon

We know that each gas giant planet was warmest when it was young. This warmth came from [internal heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_heating) from both radioactive decay and from gravitational potential energy. This warmth, in turn, means that the planet emits blackbody flux.

So this raises some interesting questions. Among them - [how much of this early daytime flux affected the day-to-day temperatures of their moons](http://www.quora.com/Are-there-certain-alignments-in-the-solar-systems-orbits-that-create-additional-interesting-effects-on-our-planets-moons-or-sun/answer/Alex-K-Chen)?